# Input Tags and Submit form outside the <form>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

I know how to submit a form from outside the form, for example:

```
<form action="Get?id_sec=120" method="post" id="form15" name="form15" style="display:none"></form>

<input type="submit" class="finish-button primary-button button" border="0"  value="Limpar pedido" form="form15" onclick="javascript:document.form15.submit();" />
```

But I want to put a tag with a reference to the `form` with javascript too, because command `form="example"` doesn't work in Internet Explorer.

example:

```
<input class="input-cep" name="pr001" id="cepfrete" type="text" form="form15"/>
```

or

```
<input type="radio" name="tipofrete" value="4" form="form15">`
```

How can I do that?

---

Hey Vince, thanks, this works. Very useful help! I need just one other thing. How can I put an `input` and `select` in the same form in jQuery?

example:

```
<input type="text" data-form="dataForm" name="external-input-2">

<Select id="selectField_1" name="selectField_1" data-form="dataForm" >   
     <option value="52" data-form="dataForm">A</option>
</Select>
```

Comment: didnt get your question correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## To submit a form from outside the form:

#### HTML

```
<form id="theForm">...</form>
<button id="submitTheForm">Click to Submit</button>
```

#### jQuery

```
$('#submitTheForm').on('click', function() {
    $('#theForm').submit();
});
```

## To include external inputs in the form submission:

#### HTML

```
<form id="theForm">...</form>
<button id="submitTheForm">Click to Submit</button>
<input type="text" data-form="theForm" name="external-input-1">
<input type="text" data-form="theForm" name="external-input-2">
```

#### jQuery

You can append the external inputs as hidden inputs to the form:

```
$('#submitTheForm').on('click', function() {
    var form = $('#theForm');

    $('input[data-form="theForm"]').each(function() {
        var input = $(this);
        var hidden = $('<input type="hidden"></input>');
        hidden.attr('name', input.attr('name'));
        hidden.val(input.val());
        form.append(hidden);
    });

    form.submit();
});
```

Comment: I cant make this work... =\, You can put a example in fiddle?

Thanks for you awnser!

Comment: @FelipeVieiraResende what errors are you getting?  Are there any JavaScript errors in the console?

Comment: Thanks i make this work =D Very useful you help!, i need a just only another thing...

how i put a Input and select in same form in jquery?

example:
<input type="text" data-form="dataForm" name="external-input-2">

<Select id="selectField_1" name="selectField_1" data-form="dataForm" >   
 <option value="52" data-form="dataForm" >A</option>
</Select>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I can completely understand your question but if you are asking how to submit a form externally in different situations, her is my answer.

For the future, just put an `id` on the form like this.

```
<form id="form15"></form>
```

Then to submit this form from anywhere, all you have to do is call the following javascript line in an onclick, a function, etc.

```
document.getElementById("form15").submit();
```

Comment: Incorrect.  form can be used as an attribute, but is not supported by internet explorer.  See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_form.asp

Comment: @VCode sorry, updated. I have never seen that before

Comment: No worries.  It isn't used very often -- it is a new attribute that was added in HTML5.  I removed my downvote, by the way.